# How to write a Python for loop in an HTML file?

Tags: python, html, flask

Let's say you pass through a Python list to an HTML file using Flask. How do you loop through that list by writing Python code in the HTML file?

Comment: You could open and read the HTML file, find and parse the list, and then loop through it.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show some effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python template engine [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org) included in Flask.

As example :

```
<ul>
    {% for elem in your_list %}
        <li>{{ elem }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use templating:

In "file.html":

```
<body>
  {%for value in values%}
     <p>{{value}}</p>
  {%endfor%}
 </body>
```

In app.py: (or file with routes)

```
@app.route("/servedata")
def send_data():
    return flask.render_templating("file.html", values=["value1", "value2", "value3"])
```